# How to mount Sram X01 pulley wheel spacers

Tags: derailleur, sram

Ive ordered a new set of pulley wheels for my Sram X01 derailleur but I do not know where to mount which spacer. The set came with 3 "deep" and 1 "flat" spacer as seen in the picture below.
I cant trust my current pulleys disk spacers as I have removed them prior and they are all mixed up.
The wheels themselves are identical.

Where do I have to put which spacer?

[image: sram x01 pulley spacers]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a look at the [SRAM parts catalogue](https://www.sram.com/globalassets/document-hierarchy/spare-parts/spare-parts-catalog/2021-sram-spare-parts-catalog.pdf); it appears you have part 11.7518.032.000.  I couldn't find any instructions specifically for it, but the catalogue has this accompanying image:

[image: SRAM rear derailleur pulley kit]

(The pulleys come with both kits 3 and 4, but I've circled 4 since 3 includes the bolts and the inner cage.)

Note the two (inner side) bushings that are circled.  The ones on the other (outer) side are shown from the back, so you can't see that they have the raised lip in the centre.  The lower inner bushing has the raised lip, but the upper inner bushing is drawn without it.

Hence I would install the odd bushing on the inside top.